# How to view the SQL created for test models in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, testing

In a current Django project I get a `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError` every time I run test — but only if I use the MySQL backend (using [mysqlclient for Python 3](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python)); the tests run fine if I use the SQLite backend:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'None, None) NOT NULL)' at line 1")`

See below for a full traceback.

Despite the tests bailing, the project (website and admin) works fine when using the build in server or the WSGI app — with both backends. The error only happens when running the tests.

I have a `models.py` in a *core* package, that defines some abstract models and mixins that are used by the other apps. There's also a `test.py` in that package, in which some models are defined, that use those abstract classes and mixins, so I can test them. I guess the error is there… somewhere; but I can't figure it out from the exception.

**Since the "real" models (not the abstract ones) are only in `test.py` and not in `models.py`, I have no clue, on how to inspect the raw SQL that is created for them (with `django-admin sql` or similar)…**

### Full Traceback

```
$ django-admin test blog -v 3
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('yogalessontv_test')...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'yogalessontv_test'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'yogalessontv_test', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: streambox, profiles, core, suit, contact, allauth, messages, staticfiles, debug_toolbar
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, carousel, sites, pages, socialaccount, blog, contenttypes, account, sessions, videos
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
Running pre-migrate handlers for application core
Running pre-migrate handlers for application pages
Running pre-migrate handlers for application blog
Running pre-migrate handlers for application videos
Running pre-migrate handlers for application carousel
Running pre-migrate handlers for application suit
Running pre-migrate handlers for application admin
Running pre-migrate handlers for application auth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application contenttypes
Running pre-migrate handlers for application sessions
Running pre-migrate handlers for application sites
Running pre-migrate handlers for application allauth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application account
Running pre-migrate handlers for application socialaccount
Running pre-migrate handlers for application debug_toolbar
  Creating tables...
    Creating table core_trimstringsmixintestmodel
    Creating table core_playtimemixintestmodel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 217, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 378, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 341, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'None, None) NOT NULL)' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=True,
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 309, in sync_apps
    editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 282, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 107, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 217, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 378, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 341, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'None, None) NOT NULL)' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused, because a [Decimal Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) in a test model was missing two arguments that where necessary (*max_digits* and *decimal_places*). This slipped by unnoticed, when using the SQLite backend.

**Still no clue on how to examine the SQL that is automatically created for test models, so any hints on this matter would be appreciated.**

Comment: this helped. Sometimes custom or 3rd party fields don't display simple errors that are occurring, like forgetting `max_length` on a char.